# Why was my permalink answer deleted in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, link-only-answers, specific-answer

I posted an answer to a question using a Stackoverflow permalink.

My answer was deleted/rejected because I used a link ?!?!?!

Can someone explain to me why an answer is not ok when you use a Permalink?

Can someone teach me how to prevent writing the same answer over and over again instead of just using a permalink?

Can someone explain to me why people that delete/remove your answer do not respond to the questions why?

Comment: Do you have a link to your deleted answer?

Comment: Also was it _only_ a link as an answer or was it an answer that used another SO post as part of the explanation?

Comment: yeah I'd like to see your answer. Can you link me to it?

Comment: If questions can be answered with the same answer and the same explanation, they're likely duplicates, and one should be closed in favor of the other. You should never post links of other answers as full answers.

Comment: Related to your earlier https://stackoverflow.com/q/51148658/2564301 on the main site? You may want to delete that.

Comment: Your post was literally: *On this link you will find a workaround so you can use a pseudoclass :parent in local CSS files.* on a question that already had more detailed answers. While that link was indeed to another SO post - it's an indicator that maybe the questions are duplicates. However, by itself, a post that literally says - "look at this other post" without any other content isn't a useful answer.

Comment: It could well be useful, but post it as a comment.  Some day you'll have enough rep to vote the question as a duplicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50664369/1249617 that;s the link of the deletion.

The deleted answer was :
[On this link][1] you will find a workaround so you can use a pseudoclass **:parent** in local CSS files.
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50657951/1249617

Comment: @john Clements. The post had more detailed answers but none of them gave a solution that makes it possible to use a **:parent** selector. The answer was unique and solves the problem.
For me the goal of Stackoverflow is to help each other.. My answer works and might need some improvements but it solves the problem without introducing many more. EG it fits exactly in what I see as the goal of this community. And if some rules make us miss our goal, we should change the rules ( or the interpretation thereof ) and not the goal..

Comment: @all The last 2 questions 
Can someone teach me how to prevent writing the same answer over and over again instead of just using a permalink?

Can someone explain to me why people that delete/remove your answer do not respond to the questions why?

remain a mystery.

Comment: @Samuel Liew A link to that duplicate question might be nice ;-)

Comment: You mean the one in the yellow notice at the top of this question?

Comment: Yep, thanks, i'll visit it

Answer (score 14):

Answers are supposed to contain their content. Linking to posts for further reading is okay, but "Here you'll find the answer [link]" is not.

If two questions can be answered by the exact same answer in a complete way, they are duplicates and should be closed as such.

If they aren't duplicates, then merely linking to another answer won't suffice.

So avoid posting link only answers in the future.

Comment: So Magisch, according to what you're saying a solution that fits multiple- non duplicate- questions may not be answered by pointing the one that needs help to a link that might help. Isn't that the 'procedure' taking over the goal (help one another)?

Comment: If a single solution fits multiple questions without alteration, these questions are duplicates. Thats what stack's operable definition of duplicate means.

Comment: @rene. I do not agree to what you are implying. You say that if an answer has multiple different (non duplicate) questions they are duplicates and should be closed.
That's the world upside down. If an answer is the answer to more than 1 question these questions do not have to be duplicates.
it's a M2M relationship.
f.i. the wheel is an answer to many different problems. People transport is one of them but that problem can also be answered by using a boat.

Comment: If that is so then Stackoverflow should rethink that definition because the real world is different as elaborated on in my comment to Rene.

Comment: @ton I made a single edit by adding the word *the*. How do I go from that to implying anything?

Comment: @Ton we might indeed put the world up-side down on Stack Exchange. The sites are different for a reason. We strive to concentrate the knowledge in one place. So if the *answers* to one question apply to other questions we consider the questions to be possible duplicate.  If it turns out that the question has a different context which invalidates the answers on the proposed duplicate, the question is genuine and has distinct answers. While you might think that the sites are geared to *help one another* in reality we're here to help future visitors. Those are better served with a one-stop visit.

Comment: @Rene.  Your missing the basics of the discussion,
_If two questions can be answered by the exact same answer in a complete way, they are duplicates and should be closed as such._
Here you imply a 1to1 relationship between an answer and a question. Taking you thoughts a little further.  
Problem how do create a 4 color drawing? A  good answer could be _use JoJoDraw._
Another problem could be how to recolor a picture? A  good answer could be _use JoJoDraw._ But in your wording that last answer made the 2nd question a duplicate; which i.m.h.o. is absolutely not correct.

Comment: If the answer is just "use JoJoDraw" then the question is a tool request and off topic, and the answer also low quality.

Comment: @Ton keep in mind I'm not the author of the answer. But I would be careful when qualifying which of us is missing the basics of the discussion. I'm sure you can construct an abstract example that matches what your impression is how duplicates should or should not work. My point (and that of @Magisch) is that if an answer can fit on two questions the questions are duplicate in the SE world. You're free to dislike that fact but this is how the close voters and dupe hammers approach duplicate selection and I personally think I'm pretty good at that.

Comment: I don't see a big difference between _'one another'_ and _'future visitors'_
If I visit Stackoverflow tomorrow I am now a future visitor. When i visit i'm part of _'one another'_

If the answer solves the problem but has 'poor quality' it should be downvoted, but it is still al valid answer that solves the problem and it is a good answer to a valid question , It might be in the wrong department but is not off-topic the questioner did not ask for a tool but for a solution and the answer provided that.
Sometimes problems experienced by people can be solved by using tools,